# JavaScript nested function prototype scope

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

I'm still having trouble figuring on how to manage scopes in JavaScript. In this particular example, I have a draw function containing certain properties and a function that needs to draw lines based on an array.

```
function Draw (canvas)
{
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.street_size = 20;
}

Draw.prototype.street = function (MAP)
{

    MAP.forEach(function (name)
    {
        this.ctx.moveTo(name.start.x,name.start.y);
        this.ctx.lineTo(name.end.x,name.end.y)
        this.ctx.stroke();
    });
}
```

Of course, "this.ctx" inside the forEach function returns "undefined". How can I make sure that Draw()'s variables are passed to the forEach function (without doing something like ctx = this.ctx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
MAP.forEach(function (name) {
    this.ctx.moveTo(name.start.x,name.start.y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(name.end.x,name.end.y)
    this.ctx.stroke();
}.bind(this));
```

[Learn more about `this`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 4):

It's common to declare the object instance variable as a new variable inside the method scope:

```
var self = this;
MAP.forEach(function (name) {
    self.ctx.moveTo(...
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to continue to use `this` as it would be ordinarily.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `this` as the second argument to `forEach()`.

```
MAP.forEach(function (name)
{
    this.ctx.moveTo(name.start.x,name.start.y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(name.end.x,name.end.y)
    this.ctx.stroke();
}, this);
```

The second argument sets the value of `this` in the callback.

---

[MDN `forEach()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - `array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])`

Comment: +1. Wasn't sure `forEach` supports it, but it does: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18.